# Laravel Migration: Can't add FK to both string types

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to create foreign keys in Laravel however when I migrate my table using artisan I am thrown the following error:

```
Copy\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:465
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server 
version for the right syntax to use near 'unsigned not null, `updated_by` varchar(255) unsigned not null, `enabled` var...' at line 1")
```

Lessons migration table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateLessonTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('lesson', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->bigInteger('module_id')->unsigned();

            $table->text('content');

            $table->string('created_by')->unsigned();

            $table->string('updated_by')->unsigned();


            $table->string('enabled');
            $table->string('position');

            $table->timestamps();

        });

        Schema::table('lesson', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('module_id')->references('id')->on('modules');
            
            $table->foreign('created_by')->references('username')->on('admins');
            $table->foreign('updated_by')->references('username')->on('admins');
        });
                
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('lesson');
    }
}
```

Admins Migration Table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateAdminsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('admins', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('username');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('fname');
            $table->string('mname');
            $table->string('lname');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('admins');
    }
}
```

I was trying to connect the created_by and updated_by columns of the Lessons table to the Admins table column 'username'. Both are in string already.

Comment: Why do you want to refer to the username instead of the id of the table? That's just duplicating data for no good reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're using `unsigned` on a column you're defining as a `string`, you can't have an `unsigned` `string`. As you're attempting to create a `FK` relationship between `lessons` and `users`, you likely want to use an `integer` column of some sort.

You could write your migration as follows:

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('lesson', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('content');
        $table->string('enabled');
        $table->string('position');

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('module_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('created_by');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('updated_by')->nullable();

        $table->foreign('module_id')->references('id')->on('modules');
        $table->foreign('created_by')->references('id')->on('admins');
        $table->foreign('updated_by')->references('id')->on('admins');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

$table->string('created_by')->unsigned();

I think the problem is that unsigned is for numbers only not string
remove unsigned and try again